# Using iFile to change lock screen passcode

Tags: jailbreak, ipod, security, ios

I would like to know where to go in iFile to be able to see your ipod passcode and be able to change the 4 digit code through iFile. I am running iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: This answer should help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84087/18387

Comment: It's in the `/var/Keychains/keychain-2.db` database somewhere.

Comment: I looked in /var/keychains/keychain -2.db and found nothing.

Comment: It's not in plaintext. I'm not an expert on the iOS keychain, yet, though. I haven't analyzed it enough, but I've done things like removed saved passwords for websites in Safari and things like that. I don't know how to edit them (they could be hashed). If I have some time, I'll do a little more forensics on it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be, is for sure in iOS6 and will ever **be encrypted** in future iOS versions. I doubt you can bypass the code.

However there is a securityleak in iOS 5 (since you have 5.0.1) I think you should check out [this post online](http://www.ijailbreak.com/iphone/ios-5-iphone-lockscreen-glitch/)

The post contains [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Vhy9_bYVIwk), on how to bypass the lock. I hope that will help you out rather than changing the code via iFile.